# How can I list folder contents in Samba share?

Tags: samba, gnome-terminal

I managed to navigate inside a Samba share using smbclient inside a terminal. Now I need to save the list of contents of a directory to a local file. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with **-c|--command command string**

```
smbclient -U <user> //192.168.0.1/Share -c "dir myFolder/*" > output.txt
```

[Man page](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/smbclient.1.html)